Problem upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04
I am trying to upgrade from 22.04 LTS to 24.04 LTS. I am having this problem:
It says:
Error during update

A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry.

But I don't have any problems with my internet. And I tried both Ethernet and Wi-Fi, and neither works.
This happens from both the software updater and the terminal, on my desktop and my laptop. My network connection is fine, I am using it right now to send this.

I'll suggest checking to see you're using an official mirror (https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+archivemirrors) as I've seen bug reports where users were using non-official mirrors that didn't support all releases.  There are other temporary causes too
